# What kind of matrix is the derivative of a Unitary matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives

Let $U(t)$ be a path consisting only of unitary matrices, where $t$ is a real number. Then is $\frac{dU(t)}{dt}$ unitary, hermitian, or skew-hermitian for all $t$? How can you tell?

Comment: Do you mean, "Under the natural identification $T_I M(n, \Bbb C) \leftrightarrow M(n, \Bbb C)$ which matrices are elements of the tangent space $T_I U(n)$?"? Either way, you should modify your question (1) to clarify this issue, and (2) include your work on the problem so far.

Comment: I've edited the question. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$U(t)$ unitary means that
$$U^*(t) U(t)=I,$$
so deriving both sides yields
$$U^*(t)U'(t)+U'^*(t)U(t)=0=U^*(t)U'(t)+(U^*(t)U'(t))^*.$$
So $U^*(t)U'(t)$ is a skew-hermitian matrix, and thus
$$U'(t)=U(t)(U^*(t)U'(t))$$is a product of a unitary matrix with a skew-hermitian.

Comment: (where $U^*(t) U'(t)$ can be any skew-hermitian matrix)

Answer (score 1):

Look at 
$$
h(t) = U(t)^{+} U(t) 
$$
Since $h$ is constant (it's the identity), its derivative is zero: 
$$
0 = U'(t)^{+} U(t) + U(t)^{+} U'(t)
$$
where I'm using the superscript "+: to indicate conjugate transpose.

If $U(a) = I$, then this simplifies somewhat to say that 
$$
U'(a)^{+} + U'(a) = 0
$$
so that the matrix $U'(a)$ is skew-hermitian.

Now for an arbitrary $U$, let $M = U(a)^{-1}$, and let 
$$
V(t) = M U(t)
$$
Then $V(t)$ is a oath in the hermitian matrices with $V(a) = I$, so $V'$ is skew-hermitian. So 
$$
U(a)^{-1} U'(a)
$$
is also skew-hermitian.